# Print integers to a new line until a certain point

Tags: java

Let's say I have a text file with this:

```
2 4 6 7 -999
9 9 9 9 -999
```

When I run the program, I should print out everything except the "-999" on each line. What I should get is:

```
 2 4 6 7 
 9 9 9 9
```

This is what I've tried:

```
public class Prac {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    while(reader.hasNextLine() && reader.nextInt() != -999) {
        int nextInt = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.print(nextInt + " ");
    }

}
```

}

I've tried using while/for loops but don't seem to get this to work and the numbers are not on different lines. I don't get why the condition does not work when I run the code and each line is not separated while printing. I've been trying to find a solution for a while and decided to ask here. It's probably an easy question but I haven't coded in a while, so let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @paulsm4 I usually come here once every few months, sorry for not being specific. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thank you.  Once I saw your code; I started working on some alternatives.  Two folks already beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `reader.nextInt()` in the `while` will consume the next int, so you will be always skipping an integer. So I would suggest:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            int nextInt = reader.nextInt();
            if (nextInt != -999)
                System.out.print(nextInt + " ");
            else
                System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

**Update**: In case you want to calculate the average for each line, as requested in your comment, you could store each value to make the calculations (see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-sum-average) other ways). The code below will do that and print the average at the end of the line:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            int nextInt = reader.nextInt();
            if (nextInt != -999) {
                System.out.print(nextInt + " ");
                values.add(nextInt);
            } else {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int value : values) {
                    sum += value;
                }
                System.out.println((float) sum / values.size());
                values.clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Excellent response.  A good solution - and a good *explanation* for what was going wrong in the OP's original code!

Comment: Thank you, do you know how you can average each line. For example, after running the first line it should be like 5, then the second one should be 9. I can't seem to do this... @y.luis

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("./input.txt"));
    while (reader.hasNextInt()) {
        int nextInt = reader.nextInt();
        if (nextInt != -999) {
            System.out.print(nextInt + " ");
        } else {
            if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you're not saving the value from `reader.nextInt()` in your while Loop.
You can try this:

```
while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    int nextInt = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print( nextInt != -999 ? nextInt + " " : "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm late to the party ... but as long as somebody else replied after you accepted, I thought I'd share the response I started writing ... but was too slow to post back before you got two other (great!) responses.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Prac {

    static final int EOL = -999;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(f)) {
            int nextInt;
            while(reader.hasNext()) {
                if ((nextInt = reader.nextInt()) == EOL)
                    System.out.println();
                else
                    System.out.print(nextInt + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTES:
1. The main problem is that you didn't capture the value of "scanner.nextInt()" in your while loop.  Consequently, you skipped every other value.

2. There's also a resource leak - you're not closing the Scanner.  That doesn't matter for a small program like this (exiting the program will close the file just fine ;)).

   One way is to do an explicit "close()".

   Another alternative, illustrated above, is the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), introduced in Java 8.